# How would one recognize a /this font?

Tags: fonts

I need to find out what font was this written with:

[image]

I have already tried http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/ but it didn't help. Do you know of some sites that display galleries of known fonts? I've only managed to get to bizzare fonts for some reason.

Anyway, any solution is welcome, thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me to be [Digital-7 Italic](http://www.styleseven.com/php/get_product.php?product=Digital-7) font. See the [preview](http://www.dafont.com/digital-7.font?text=WESE).

Answer (score 1):

Is it something similar to this? : http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/peggo/hexaround/regular/

You can try to take a look on http://www.fontsquirrel.com/ or on http://www.google.com/fonts/ but it won't be easy to find. Maybe you will find something similar which you can use. Good luck anyway

Comment: updated the picture, the first thing isn't it, i'm having a look at the google link. thx :)